# Is it possible to inherit from an extension class in ODOO?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

On `addons/delivery/sale.py` we have a class that inherits `sale.order` at line 39:

```
class sale_order(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
```

That's an extension class ( no `_name` )

Is there a way to inherit from this class and rewrite one of is methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Paulo Farinha Silva : The code snippet you gave is already way to extend the class and you can ten over-ride or overload any method and either call super method or you can skip calling super method. Example snippet is :

```
#Original definition v8 addons/delivery/sale.py  line no 36 :
class sale_order(osv.Model):
    _name = "sale.order"
#Example method on sale order calss line #601
def action_wait(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
```

This is inherited and method mention above is already over-rider and code look like this:

```
#Original definition v8 /addons/sale_stock/sale_stock.py  line no 30 :
class sale_order(osv.Model):
    _name = "sale.order"

 #this is method originally defined in parent class and being over-ride here,
def action_wait(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    #Your Code goes here
    res = super(sale_order, self).action_wait(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    #Your Code goes here
    return res
```

This way you can over-rider method and can play  with all  Model methods at a time and fields also.

Bests